# Heimdallr.swift can not use access token

Tags: swift, oauth, oauth-2.0, swift2

I am using the Heimdallr.swift repository in my swift app to login with OAuth2 Password grant. But after getting the "success" message, i can still not access the protected resources. Do anyone know how to save the token that you receive or what the problem might be?

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let username: String = usernameTextfield.text!;
    let password: String = passwordTextfield.text!;

    let tokenURL = NSURL(string: "http://challyme.dk:8888/index.php/api/v1.1/oauth/access_token")!

    let identifier = "id0"
    let secret = "secret0"

    let credentials = OAuthClientCredentials(id: identifier, secret: secret)

    let heimdall = Heimdallr(tokenURL: tokenURL, credentials: credentials)

    heimdall.requestAccessToken(username: username, password: password) { result in
        switch result {
        case .Success:
            self.callUserInfo(heimdall)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LogedInView") as UIViewController
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        case .Failure:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("Wrong password or username")
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You entered the wrong username or password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

- The method that should display the protected resources:

  ```
  func callUserInfo(heimdall: Heimdallr) {
        let urlPath = "http://linkToResources"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        heimdall.authenticateRequest(request, completion: { result in
          switch result {
          case .Success(let request):
              let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                  let json = JSON(data: data!);
                  print(response!.description);
                  if response != nil {
                       print(json);
                   } else {
                      print(json[999].error) // "Array[999] is out of bounds"
                   }

               }
              task.resume()

          case .Failure:
              print("failure")
          }
      })
  }
  ```

Best regards
Anders B. Christensen

Comment: A little late, but were you able to solve your problem?